# How to publish an artifact with pom-packaging in SBT?

Tags: sbt

I have a multi-project build in SBT where some projects should aggregate dependencies and contain no code. So then clients could depend on these projects as a single dependency instead of directly depending on all of their aggregated dependencies. With Maven, this is a common pattern, e.g. when using Spring Boot.

In SBT, I figured I can suppress the generation of the empty artifacts by adding this setting to these projects:

```
packagedArtifacts := Classpaths.packaged(Seq(makePom)).value
```

However, the `makePom` task writes `<packaging>jar</packaging>` in the generated POM. But now that there is no JAR anymore, this should read `<packaging>pom</packaging>` instead.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

This question is a bit old, but I just came across the same issue and found a solution.  The original answer does point to the right page where this info can be found, but here is an example.  It uses the `pomPostProcess` setting to transform the generated POM right before it is written to disk. Essentially, we loop over all the XML nodes, looking for the element we care about and then rewrite it.

```scala
import scala.xml.{Node => XmlNode, NodeSeq => XmlNodeSeq, _}
import scala.xml.transform._

pomPostProcess := { node: XmlNode =>
  val rule = new RewriteRule {
    override def transform(n: XmlNode): XmlNodeSeq = n match {
      case e: Elem if e != null && e.label == "packaging" =>
        <packaging>pom</packaging>
      case _ => n
    }
  }
  new RuleTransformer(rule).transform(node).head
},
```

Comment: Upvoted as this works, and might be useful for cases where sbt isn't doing what you want. I've submitted an answer where it can do what you want without manipulating the XML directly.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could modify the result pom as described here: [Modifying the generated POM](http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Publishing.html#Modifying+the+generated+POM)

Comment: I tried this before, I can include a `packaging` element there, but it gets ignored.

Comment: It appears that you were looking at the `pomExtra` setting. The key is to use the `pomPostProcess` setting as shown below.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable publishing the default artifacts of JAR, sources, and docs, then opt in explicitly to publishing the POM. sbt produces and publishes a POM only, with `<packaging>pom</packaging>`.

```scala
// This project has no sources, I want <packaging>pom</pom> with dependencies
lazy val bundle = project
  .dependsOn(moduleA, moduleB)
  .settings(
    publishArtifact := false, // Disable jar, sources, docs
    publishArtifact in makePom := true,
  )

lazy val moduleA = project
lazy val moduleB = project
lazy val moduleC = project
```

Run `sbt bundle/publishM2` to verify the POM in `~/.m2/repository`.

I dare say this is *almost* intuitive, a rare moment of pleasant surprise with sbt

I confirmed this with current sbt 1.3.9, and 1.0.1, the oldest launcher I happen to have installed on my machine.

The [Artifacts](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Artifacts.html) page in the reference docs may be helpful, perhaps this trick should be added there.

Comment: Shame this is just for pom and doesn't allow you to set a different type